# Gitlab auto merge when build succeeds not working

Tags: gitlab, git-merge, gitlab-ci

I have a quite simple question. We have setup Gitlab CI and want to allow auto merge as soon as the build succeeds for some of our branches.

Thing is, we see that the build passes, but the merge does not actually happen and the status stays at "to be merged automatically once the build succeeds".

Do you have any idea why?

I attached a screenshot of the bogus behaviour.

[image: Merge succeeded but MR not merged]

**EDIT:** Some additional information that was requested:

- It looks like no background job is put in the queue where I activate a "automatic merge when build succeeds
- When a build finishes running, no background jobs is triggered as far as I can see. Nothing new being scheduled, dead or in progress.
- I also don't see anything crazy or ERROR like in the logs.
- Two screenshots of my dashboard as a MR with an automated build runs :

[image: Dashboard during MR with auto merge 1] 
[image: Dashboard during MR with auto merge 2]

Thanks, 
Julien

Comment: you mean if anyone pushed changes to any of the branches then code should get merge to master branch on Success?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @DeendayalGarg. Automatic merge should , I guess, as the name indicates Merge the branch that is being proposed in the Merge request if the build passes. Now, the build is successful, but the merge did not happen. I do not understand why :)

Comment: Just found out that we are not the only one in that case : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21138#note_16578985

Comment: I experienced the same thing on our last merge request. Canceled the auto-merge and merged it manually. Doesn't answer the question, but, it works!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your merge job is scheduled or dead.

- Use your admin account and click the `Admin Area` button.
- Click `Monitoring` -> `Background Jobs`
  [image]
- Then,click the `dashboard` and check the if your merge job is in the `Scheduled` queue or `Dead` queue.
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are indeed some jobs in the dead queue, and they seem somehow related but I am not sure whether those are the ones blocking the actual merges. You can find a screenshot here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4286043/Spacemetric/gitlab/2016-09-19_07h41_39.png

Comment: It might be that this error blocks the merge to actually happen, but I would be surprised :S

Comment: I have just checked, and it looks like no background job is put in the queue where I activate a "automatic merge when build succeeds" MR. I am not sure why :S

Comment: Even a ci runner job?

Comment: Those two screenshots are the things I have in my dashboard as a MR with an automated build runs : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4286043/Spacemetric/gitlab/2016-09-19_10h40_02.png and https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4286043/Spacemetric/gitlab/2016-09-19_10h40_58.png. Our build runs on another machine though, could it be that it comes from that?

Comment: no, I set up a github runner for iOS on another mac.

Comment: The build has just finished running, and no background jobs were triggered as far as I could see. Nothing new being scheduled, dead or in progress. Is there Anything else to be done than just ticking the automerge box to be done for this feature to work? I am confused :S

Comment: I also don't see anything crazy or ERROR like in the logs. Maybe I should check on the runner side.

Comment: Well, that's interesting :). You get the bounty even though your answer does not solve our problem. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: No worries, it is a pleasure :).